# Is there a way to auto update an excel formula inserted in an email in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-excel, email, microsoft-outlook

I send these kind of mails to intimate people about upcoming meeting, the format I prepare in Excel 2013 and paste it in Outlook 2013 (as a table, not as an image)

Now one of the columns I put as 'Days Remaining' which basically tells the users how many days are there to the review, the image below will show how it looks:

[image]

Now the numbers of days remaining will be correct the day I send the mail, but when somebody opens the mail at a later date, it would not sort of show the true number.

Is there a way to auto-update this number inside the Outlook mail, as it works in an Excel Sheet?

A non-vba approach would be welcome, because with macros, its difficult to implement in other systems.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a similar topic covered on stackoverflow. You can find it  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711400/how-do-i-set-up-an-email-template-with-dynamic-dates-or-alternatively-create-a)

Not sure if it will be of much use to you, but should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by Matthew might work but probably will not for most people using work systems as they are likely to have VBA turned off in Outlook for security reasons.

They would need to allow VBA to be turned on - probably to only trust signed macros. You would then need to sign the macro and distribute it to them. Quite a lot of bother to go through simply to get the text to update.

Alternatives would be to try embedding JavaScript - though this is also unlikely to work for most peopole. Embedding a web page as an iFrame (also likely to be blocked by security settings). Or, perhaps the best option, sending them a set meeting invites instead.

One other springs to mind, though I'm not certain it would work, would be to send the information as an embedded InfoPath form. Not sure to be honest how dynamic that is when embedded.

Comment: I was hoping for a non-VBA solution, especially when it involves a lot of people... Was hoping for a simple solution, but this sounds complex, maybe not worth the effort. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I agree - almost certainly not worth it I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve the desired result, insert Excel table as object, not by copy-pasting. Follow the Insert -> Object on Outlook message form and select Microsoft Excel Worksheet

Comment: Does not work, outlook converts the worksheet as an image while sending.

Comment: I tried converting it to Rich Text format, which does not convert it to an image, but it does not auto-update it.